# Xamarin Forms Styling using StyleClass vs Style attribute

Tags: xaml, styles, xamarin.forms

We're building a Xamarin Forms app we've noticed we could style an element in 2 ways by creating styles in the App.xaml ResourceDictionary

**Class and StyleClass option**

In App.xaml we'll write

```
        <Style Class="EntryStandard" TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#575e62" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#9facb3" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        </Style>
```

Then this gets used in one of the contentpages like this

```
<Entry StyleClass="EntryStandard" Placeholder="Login Name" Text="{Binding EntryEmailAddress}" />
```

**Key and Style option**

This is what we write under App.xaml

```
      <Style x:Key="ButtonMainMenu_Purple" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#5d4785" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#FFFFFF" />
        </Style>
```

And then we use the following in our contentpages

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonMainMenu_Purple}" Text="Friends" Command="{Binding OnFriendsButtonCommand}" />
```

Both work fine, I just wanted to know which one is better than the other and why?

Comment: :( looks like everyone's on Christmas break....

Comment: The "Key and Style option" does not work for me.  I get: "StaticResource not found for key Banner'".  I assume the Style is defined in Application.Resources in the App.xaml file?  The "Class and StyleClass option" works fine.

Comment: Its an old post. Forms has a changed a lot since then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular styles follow the standard, relatively inflexible WPF model. Style classes includes cascade semantics and are part of the new [theme](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/themes/) support. They are poorly documented, however, and still in beta.

Comment: Yes.  I have found that I cannot Release Build with the current Beta themes.  So beware.